# please explain the reason about this exception? & also give solution for these type of problems?

Tags: xcode, macos

2013-01-22 16:51:10.040 Applecalcultaor[339:f803]

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ApplecalculatorViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'**

First throw call stack:

(0x13ba052 0x154bd0a 0x1362a78 0x13629e9 0xd6f0d 0xd73a9 0xd75cb 0x37a73 0x37ce2 0x37ea8 0x3ed9a 0x29c5 0xf9d6 0x108a6 0x1f743 0x201f8 0x13aa9 0x12a4fa9 0x138e1c5 0x12f3022 0x12f190a 0x12f0db4 0x12f0ccb 0x102a7 0x11a9b 0x26fd 0x2665)

terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Google it... many resolved.

Comment: Kindly provide some information on what you are trying to do and how you encountered this error and what you expect people on SO to do for u!

Comment: i got solution for the above probelm. just link with fileowner & give buttons prefrences.

Answer (score 1):

Open your xib in Interface Builder. Check if UIView is connected to your File's owner. If not, just drag with right mouse button (or cmd+left mouse button) from File's owner to UIView and connect to view property.